# how to set environment variable for MariaDB version 10.1.21 database in Linux mint system

Tags: mysql, linux, linux-mint

How to set environment variable for MariaDB database version 10.1.21 in Linux mint operating system and after setting environment variable how I check the variable is set or not.

**I tried below command but didn't work.**

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is fine but `export` command will create environment variables for the current shell only. Each child process of that shell will recognize the added variable. 
In order to set an environment variable permanently for a particular user you should add the line:
`PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/`

into the file `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

Further if you want to add for all users (in special cases), you can add that line to in system-wide configuration files present in following directories and files: `/etc/environment`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`. 
These variables are loaded every time system is powered on and logged in either locally or remotely by any user.